# pyproject.toml always includes a file from test (excluded) module

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am trying to package my python project with following sturcture.

```
testpkg/
|> lib/
  |> __init__.py
  |> mod1/
    |> __init__.py
|> scripts/
  |> __init__.py
  |> main.py #has a "main" method
|> test/
  |> __init__.py
  |> test_lib.py
  |> lib/
    |> __init__.py
    |> mod1
      |> __init__.py
|> pyproject.toml
|> LICENCE
|> README.md
```

Following is my `pyproject.toml`.

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=68.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["lib*", "scripts"]
exclude = ["test*"]
namespaces = false

[project]
name = "testpkg"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    {name="JustME", email="test@example.com"}
]
description = "Test package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.12"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent"
]

[project.scripts]
main = "scripts.main:main"
```

I installed this package in editable mode with `pip intall -e .`, which created "testpkg.egg-info" in current directory and a wrapper for `main` in "site-packages" which was expected.

My issue is that `testpkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` looks like following which seems to bundle one file from `test` package (`test/test_lib.py`) as well.

```
LICENCE
README.md
pyproject.toml
lib/__init__.py
lib/mod1/__init__.py
scripts/__init__.py
scripts/main.py
test/test_lib.py
testpkg.egg-info/PKG-INFO
testpkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
testpkg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
testpkg.egg-info/entry_points.txt
testpkg.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

1. How do I ensure that nothing from test is included in build?
2. Is there a better package definition? I do not want to list every package (top level or nested) and can't change layout of the project.

I would like to use setuptools and pypoject.toml (not use MAIFEST.in, setup.py etc.) if possible. Also, what exactly "namespaces" means here?

I have tried this with CPython 3.11 and 3.12. I am new to packaging and looked at few resources. If I read [this](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#setuptools.discovery.FlatLayoutPackageFinder.DEFAULT_EXCLUDE) correctly, "test" should be automatically excluded.